# Realm query nested object

Tags: swift, realm

Hello everyone I'm having difficulties archiving one thing with a query of nested object. I have two realm object Championship and Game.

```
class Championship: Object {
    dynamic var id: Int = 0
    dynamic var name: String = ""
    let games = List<Game>

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
       return "id"
    }

}

class Game: Object {
    dynamic var id: Int = 0
    dynamic var homeTeamName: String = ""
    dynamic var awayTeamName: String = ""
    dynamic var status: String = "" //"inprogress", "finished", "scheduled"

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
       return "id"
    }

}
```

And basically I want to retrieve all championships that have games with status "inprogress", so what I'm doing to archive that is:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
realm.objects(Championship.self).filter("ANY games.status = 'inprogress'")
```

What that query is doing is giving me all championships that have at least one game with that status, but is also giving me all the the games from that championship, but actually I just want the games with "inprogress" status.

There any way for doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take two approaches here. If you want all games with `inprogress` status, you could write this:

```
let inProgressGames = realm.objects(Championship.self)
                           .flatMap { $0.games }
                           .filter { $0.status == "inprogress" }
```

This will return you all games in progress inside `[Game]` array. `flatMap` is used to combine all games from all championships and `filter` is used to filter all games with `inProgress` status.

If you want championships where every game is `inprogress` you could write:

```
let inProgressChampionships = realm.objects(Championship.self).filter {
   let inProgressGames = $0.games.filter { $0.status == "inprogress"}
   return $0.games.count == inProgressGames.count
}
```

This will return array of `Championship` where each game is `inprogress`.

Other that that, I would recommend using `enum` for game status instead of hard-coded strings.

Comment: I was focusing to much in realm queries. The second suggestion did the job for me

Comment: I had to tailor a little bit your suggestion, because the result of filtering the games was coming the same as doing my realm query... so for now what I did is for each championship section I filter the live games. I don't know if that is the most efficient way to go... but for now will do. Thx once again for the suggestion